# where is the wrong connecting jquery and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My jquery code:

```
     var getid;
    var urllink;
    $("li").click(function(){
    getid = $(this).attr('id');
   switch(getid){
        case "brief":

        urllink = "allbriefs.txt";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'showtext.php',
            data: "urlname=" +  urllink,
            type: "POST"
        })

        break;
        default: break;
    }

})
```

my 'showtext.php' code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

<?php
        $filename = $_POST["urlname"];
        $keyword = $_POST["keyword"];
        $myfile = fopen($filename,"r") or die("unable to open file");
        echo fread($myfile, 120);
        fclose($myfile);
        ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```

html code:

```
<p id="brief" > <?php include 'showtext.php' ?></p>
```

Those are not working and giving the error of " Undefined index: urlname in..." . I cant make out where is the problem.

Comment: maybe try `data: { urlname: urllink }`

Comment: {urlname: urllink},

Comment: if you directly access the page with the include of course you'll get an undefined, you handle the response on the success block of ajax, and your `keyword` index is missing on the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include the `php file` in the html, so delete this row:

```
<p id="brief" > <?php include 'showtext.php' ?></p>
```

the ajax will automatically call that specific page and return its content in a variable:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'showtext.php',
    data: {urlname: urllink},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result); // showtext.php result
    }
});
```

If you want to achieve your example's result, you can do something like:

```
HTML:
<p id="brief"></p>

JS:
$.ajax({
    url: 'showtext.php',
    data: {urlname: urllink},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result); // showtext.php result
        $('#brief').html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Alhamdulillah. It worked. May Allah give you the best gift.